# Pandas DataFrame.unstack() Changes Order of Row and Column Headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have run into the following problem of sorting the row and column headers.

Here is how to reproduce this:

```
X =pd.DataFrame(dict(x=np.random.normal(size=100), y=np.random.normal(size=100)))
A=pd.qcut(X['x'], [0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0]) #create a factor
B=pd.qcut(X['y'], [0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0]) # create another factor

g = X.groupby([A,B])['x'].mean() #do a two-way bucketing


print g 

#this gives the following and so far so good

x                 y               
[-2.315, -0.843]  [-2.58, -0.567]    -1.041167
                  (-0.567, 0.0321]   -1.722926
                  (0.0321, 0.724]    -1.245856
                  (0.724, 3.478]     -1.240876
(-0.843, -0.228]  [-2.58, -0.567]    -0.576264
                  (-0.567, 0.0321]   -0.501709
                  (0.0321, 0.724]    -0.522697
                  (0.724, 3.478]     -0.506259
(-0.228, 0.382]   [-2.58, -0.567]     0.175768
                  (-0.567, 0.0321]    0.214353
                  (0.0321, 0.724]     0.113650
                  (0.724, 3.478]     -0.013758
(0.382, 2.662]    [-2.58, -0.567]     0.983807
                  (-0.567, 0.0321]    1.214640
                  (0.0321, 0.724]     0.808608
                  (0.724, 3.478]      1.515334
Name: x, dtype: float64

#Now let's make a two way table and here is the problem:

HTML(g.unstack().to_html())
```

This shows:

```
y                 (-0.567, 0.0321]  (0.0321, 0.724]  (0.724, 3.478]  [-2.58, -0.567]
x                                                                                   
(-0.228, 0.382]           0.214353         0.113650       -0.013758         0.175768
(-0.843, -0.228]         -0.501709        -0.522697       -0.506259        -0.576264
(0.382, 2.662]            1.214640         0.808608        1.515334         0.983807
[-2.315, -0.843]         -1.722926        -1.245856       -1.240876        -1.041167
```

Note how the headers are no longer sorted. I am wondering what is a good way to solve this problem so as to making interactive work easy.

To further track down where the problem is, run the following:

```
g.unstack().columns
```

It gives me this:
     Index([(-0.567, 0.0321], (0.0321, 0.724], (0.724, 3.478], [-2.58, -0.567]],    dtype=object)

Now compare this with B.levels:

```
B.levels
Index([[-2.58, -0.567], (-0.567, 0.0321], (0.0321, 0.724], (0.724, 3.478]], dtype=object)
```

Obviously the order originally in Factor is lost.

Now to make the matter even worse, let's do a multi-level cross table:

```
g2 = X.groupby([A,B]).agg('mean')
g3 = g2.stack().unstack(-2)
HTML(g3.to_html())
```

It shows something like:

```
y                   (-0.567, 0.0321]  (0.0321, 0.724]  (0.724, 3.478]  
x                                                                       
(-0.228, 0.382]  x          0.214353         0.113650       -0.013758   
                 y         -0.293465         0.321836        1.180369   
(-0.843, -0.228] x         -0.501709        -0.522697       -0.506259   
                 y         -0.204811         0.324571        1.167005   
(0.382, 2.662]   x          1.214640         0.808608        1.515334   
                 y         -0.195446         0.161198        1.074532   
[-2.315, -0.843] x         -1.722926        -1.245856       -1.240876   
                 y         -0.392896         0.335471        1.730513
```

With both the row and column labels sorted incorrectly.

Thanks.

Comment: This is an excellent question. The strange part is that these bin objects are actually just strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems like a little bit of a hack, but here goes:

```
In [11]: g_unstacked = g.unstack()

In [12]: g_unstacked
Out[12]:
y                 (-0.565, 0.12]  (0.12, 0.791]  (0.791, 2.57]  [-2.177, -0.565]
x
(-0.068, 0.625]         0.389408       0.267252       0.283344          0.258337
(-0.892, -0.068]       -0.121413      -0.471889      -0.448977         -0.462180
(0.625, 1.639]          0.987372       1.006496       0.830710          1.202158
[-3.124, -0.892]       -1.513954      -1.482813      -1.394198         -1.756679
```

Making use the fact that [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) preserves order* (grabbing the unique first terms in from the index of g):

```
In [13]: g.index.get_level_values(0).unique()
Out[13]:
array(['[-3.124, -0.892]', '(-0.892, -0.068]', '(-0.068, 0.625]',
       '(0.625, 1.639]'], dtype=object)
```

*As you can see, these are in the correct order.*

Now you can [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by this:

```
In [14]: g_unstacked.reindex(g.index.get_level_values(0).unique())
Out[14]:
y                 (-0.565, 0.12]  (0.12, 0.791]  (0.791, 2.57]  [-2.177, -0.565]
[-3.124, -0.892]       -1.513954      -1.482813      -1.394198         -1.756679
(-0.892, -0.068]       -0.121413      -0.471889      -0.448977         -0.462180
(-0.068, 0.625]         0.389408       0.267252       0.283344          0.258337
(0.625, 1.639]          0.987372       1.006496       0.830710          1.202158
```

Which is now in the correct order.

*Update (I missed that the columns were also not in order).*
You can use the same trick for the columns (you'll have to chain these operations):

```
In [15]: g_unstacked.reindex_axis(g.index.get_level_values(1).unique(), axis=1)
```

** this is the reason Series unique is significantly faster than `np.unique`.*

Comment: This only works on the row header. The column header still has the wrong order. Also, it is kind of tedious to type in iPython. Is there a more succinct way?

Comment: Yup, it's definitely a hack... (whooops assumed the cols were in order, the same hack can be applied to them). Maybe someone else will have a better way!

Comment: Do you know how to reindex if the row index is a MultiIndex? I edited my question and the last part shows the situation where it is a multi level index. Thanks.

Comment: @TomBennett to be honest, it might be better to ask that part as a new question (since this parts already quite involved)... and I think the more general question could be interesting, but I'll have a quick think. I posted an [enhancement idea](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3942) easrlier today which would make doing this quite easy!