# Unstack or Pivot Only Some Columns

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
DF = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B','B'], 
                   'COL2' : [1,2,3,1,2,3],
                   'COL3': [11032, 1960, 11400, 11355, 8, 7], 
                   'year': ['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021']})
DF

        COL1 COL2 COL3  COL4    year
     0    A   1   2    11032    2016
     1    A   2   2    1960     2017
     2    A   3   4    11400    2018
     3    B   1   2    11355    2019
     4    B   2   2    8        2020
     5    B   3   4    7        2021
```

I only want to unstack "COL4" and "Year" by way of COL1 while keeping COL2 and COL3 in tact. The end result should look like this:

```
    COL2    COL3    COL4 (A)    year (A)    COL4 (B)    year (B)
0      1     2     11032       2016         11355       2019
1      2     2     1960        2017         8           2020
2      3     4     11400       2018         7           2021
```

Also, what if there are some records with no "A"s under "COL1"?

I'm assuming the solution will look for records that match on "COL2" and "COL3" when unstacking, (if that's the method used).
By that, I mean if the order of columns is not sorted like in my example, it will generate the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set multiindex by first 3 columns and use [unstack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with `level=0`.
Then you can rename columns names - or by `levels` and `labels` or by custom names.

```
#  COL1  COL2  COL3   COL4  year
#0    A     1     2  11032  2016
#1    A     2     2   1960  2017
#2    A     3     4  11400  2018
#3    B     1     2  11355  2019
#4    B     2     2      8  2020
#5    B     3     4      7  2021

DF = DF.set_index(['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3'])
DF = DF.unstack(0).reset_index()
print DF
#     COL2 COL3   COL4         year
#COL1                A      B     A     B
#0       1    2  11032  11355  2016  2019
#1       2    2   1960      8  2017  2020
#2       3    4  11400      7  2018  2021

levels = DF.columns.levels
labels = DF.columns.labels
DF.columns = levels[0][labels[0]]
print DF
#   COL2  COL3   COL4   COL4  year  year
#0     1     2  11032  11355  2016  2019
#1     2     2   1960      8  2017  2020
#2     3     4  11400      7  2018  2021
DF.columns = ['COL2','COL3','COL4','COL5','COL6','COL7']
print DF
#   COL2  COL3   COL4   COL5  COL6  COL7
#0     1     2  11032  11355  2016  2019
#1     2     2   1960      8  2017  2020
#2     3     4  11400      7  2018  2021
```

But if columns `COL2` and `COL3` have different order, you can use [little hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17157110/2901002) by Andy Hayden:

```
#  COL1  COL2  COL3   COL4  year
#0    A     4     6  11032  2016
#1    A     9     2   1960  2017
#2    A     8     4  11400  2018
#3    B     4     6  11355  2019
#4    B     9     2      8  2020
#5    B     8     4      7  2021
DF = DF.set_index(['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3'])

index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[DF.index.get_level_values(1).unique(),
                   DF.index.get_level_values(2).unique()],
                   labels=[[0, 1, 2],
                   [0, 1, 2]])
DF = DF.unstack(0)
DF = DF.reindex(index).reset_index()
print DF
#     level_0 level_1   COL4         year
#COL1                      A      B     A     B
#0          4       6  11032  11355  2016  2019
#1          9       2   1960      8  2017  2020
#2          8       4  11400      7  2018  2021
levels = DF.columns.levels
labels = DF.columns.labels
DF.columns = levels[0][labels[0]]
print DF
#   level_0  level_1   COL4   COL4  year  year
#0        4        6  11032  11355  2016  2019
#1        9        2   1960      8  2017  2020
#2        8        4  11400      7  2018  2021
DF.columns = ['COL2','COL3','COL4','COL5','COL6','COL7']
print DF
#   COL2  COL3   COL4   COL5  COL6  COL7
#0     4     6  11032  11355  2016  2019
#1     9     2   1960      8  2017  2020
#2     8     4  11400      7  2018  2021
```